# Set specific envionment variables on every login

Tags: environment-variables, login

It sounds like an easy task, but I could not achieve it so far:

Whenever a (graphical) login occurs on Debian 11, I want to conditionally (e.g. if $XDG_DEBUG == 1, then ...) set specific environment variables for this user. The environment variables should be set on any terminal, which gets invoked by the user later on (e.g. `bash` and `zsh`) for `Gnome Desktop` and `Mate Desktop`.

**Important**: The environment variables should be set on every login, so for the following sequence: Login, Logout, Login again, they are set twice. There is no reboot involved.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add these variables into `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` files in your home directory. These files are automatically loaded each time a shell is started (one for `bash` another for `zsh`).

If you want a more global setting - create your own `.my_envvar` (or any name you like) and add into both `*rc` files a code like:

```
if [ -e $HOME/.my_envar ] ; then
   source $HOME/.my_envar
fi
```

If you want these variables be set for all users, not just yourself, go to `/etc` and check existence of a directory `/etc/profile.d`. Add your file with variables into it. These files would be loaded from `/etc/profile` (you will find a special loop for this in it).

Or if your OS is not smart enough, you can go `/etc/profile` and add your special variables directly into it. Or create your own `/etc/profile.d`.

BTW, for variable like `XDG_DEBUG` (or any debug variables) it is better to set them in a special shell script which will run the application you want to debug. Do not setup it up globally, or you will drown in a debug information from multiple applications.